# Convert a list of dictionaries to numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Let the given dictionaries are

```
d = [{'a':1,'b':4},{'b':2}]
```

So basically I want a matrix like this

```
  | 'a' | 'b'  |
 _______________
  |  1  |  4   |
  |  na |  2   |
```

How can I efficiently achieve this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Pandas DataFrame constructor will immediately give you the result you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(d).values
```

The `.values` part on the end converts the result to a NumPy array, which is what you asked for.  Some people would just work directly with the DataFrame instead.

Comment: Using DataFrame might be convenient, but if speed is a concern it seems like overkill. I've read a (hopefully credible) article that specifically warns about the cost of creating a DataFrame: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/careful-when-using-sklearn-pandas-production-environment-longbin-chen/. So, I'm curious what the most efficient method would be if we wanted to avoid the overhead of creating a Pandas DataFrame.